# iPhone programatically turn on/off wifi & 3G

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I researched about how can I programmatically turn on/off wifi & 3G. For me it doesn't matter whether it is done by private API and even I had gone through Reachability Code but not able to accomplish the task.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3394-howto-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-bluetooth.html has a discussion on this issue